# Fastest way to read and work with a binary file

Tags: autoit

Im working on a script that work with a Binary file Inside of loop and read its bytes Consecutive , (also be able to Go back and forth inside the file (savepos) (setpos))

But I dont know I need to use what method so its not bad for performance

My first attempt was to use FileRead with FileHandle, But sadly This made the speed of the program slower as the program progressed and read further from file  (Program finish after like 30 min for a 10MB file)

```
$File = FileOpen($Path, 16)
$tTimer = TimerInit()
$ndx = 4
for $i=0 to 100000
    $test = FileRead($File, $ndx)
    $ndx += 4
    ConsoleWrite($test & @CRLF)
Next
ConsoleWrite(TimerDiff($ttimer) &" Sekunden"& @CRLF)
```

So I tried to first read whole File into a variable and then read the binary from it with BinaryMid
But this method was even more slower...

```
$File = FileOpen($Path, 16)
$Readfilee = FileRead($File)
$tTimer = TimerInit()
$ndx = 4
for $i=0 to 100000
    $test = _BinaryRead(4)
    ConsoleWrite($test & @CRLF)
Next
ConsoleWrite(round(TimerDiff($ttimer) /1000,2) &" Sekunden"& @CRLF)

Func _BinaryRead($iCount)
  $ndx += $iCount
  Return BinaryMid($Readfilee, $GNOW - $iCount, $iCount)
EndFunc
```

so I want to know what can I do for reading Bin file as fast as possible?

sorry if its not a good question, Im new in autoit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the file byte-by-byte, the function `FileRead()` do everything for you in only one step, you can use something like this:

```
$hFile = FileOpen($Path, $FO_BINARY)
$tTimer = TimerInit()
$bFileContent = FileRead($hFile)
FileClose($hFile)
; Now you can use $bFileContent as you want.
ConsoleWrite(TimerDiff($ttimer) &" Sekunden"& @CRLF)
```